# How do I change the color of only the props from another component

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vue-component

I want to change only the color of the string in 'subMsg'. I don't want the color to affect the 'HomeContent' too.

```
<template>
  <div class="submit">
      <HomeContent v-bind:style="{ color: color }" subMsg="* Required"/>
       <div id="buttons">  
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light"><router-link to="/about">Back</router-link></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit"><a href="#">Submit</a></button>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I alocated a different string to the same subMsg in another component but in this component. I want the color to the different for only this subMsg component.

```
import HomeContent from "@/components/HomeContent.vue";
export default {
 name: "Submit",
  components: {
    HomeContent
  },
  data() {
  return {
    color: "red"
  }
}
}
```

Is it possible to change the color?

Comment: You'll (probably) have to do that inside of `<HomeContent />`

Comment: I have already given another string to the same 'subMsg' in another component. Changing it inside <HomeComponent /> will affect that one too.  <div class="home">
    <HomeContent subMsg = "This is a pillar measure." />
  <div id="buttons"> ```

Comment: you send props to HomeContent. If you can share the code of the other component where you want to change color in, that would be helpful

Comment: @user9879287 The component I want to change is in the code I posted in the question. `<HomeComponent /> will affect that one too. <div class="home"> <HomeContent subMsg = "This is a pillar measure." /> </div>` This code is a different component where I have used the same props "subMsg" to display a different message from what is found in the question. I want to change the color of the "subMsg" in this code ===> `<div class="submit">
      <HomeContent v-bind:style="{ color: color }" subMsg="* Required"/></div>` as seen in the question.

Comment: @Alberta, can you share the codes in HomeContent component

Comment: This is the code in HomeContent `<template>
  <div class="hello"> <div class="card"> <div class="card-content"><h1>{{ msg }}</h1>  <p>{{ subMsg }}</p> </div>  </div></div></template>

<script> export default {name: "hello",
  data() { return { msg: "Data Collection"  };},
  props: { subMsg: String,}}
</script>` @user9879287 I hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this:
parent component:

```
//HTML part
<HomeContent :subMsg="{color:subMsgColor,message:'* Required'}"/>
// script part
data() {
  return {
    subMsgColor: "red"
  }
```

HomeContent component:

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-content">
        <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
        <p :style="{color:subMsg.color}">{{ subMsg.message }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

  <script>
    export default {
      name: "hello",
      data() {
        return {
          msg: "Data Collection"
        };
      },
      props: {
        subMsg: {
           type:Object,
           default:null
         }
      }
    } 
   </script>
```